# spring. "schemaLocation ... must have even number of URI's"

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xsd

snippet from my xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!--            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  -->
<!--            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"> -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="myPackage" />
```

after execution I see following message:

> WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Ignored XML
>   validation warning org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14;
>   columnNumber: 80; SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value =
>   'http://www.springfr amework.org/schema/beans
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
>   http://www.spri ngframework.org/schema/util
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
>   http://www.springfra mework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd'
>   must have even number of URI's.
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)

How to solve this problem right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `schemaLocation` value should be of the form

```
namespace-name schema-location [namespace-name schema-location]
```

You're missing

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
```

before

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
```

It should therefore be

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

Note that I've changed the `util` schema to version 3.1. Don't mix and match. Use all the same versions.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, you declare a namespace with `xmlns:some-namespace-name`. The `schemaLocation` serves to  point to the location where the schema resides so that the XML parser can validate the XML in the document.

Comment: I have 4 - *xmlns:xsi xmlns:aop xmlns:util xmlns:context* at the begining of file and 3(beans util context) at the end. Is it normally?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, that's normal. `xmlns:xsi` is for the default XML schema. See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/934e21d0-7b44-4cfc-a9c4-89e9c66aebbc/whats-xmlnsxsi-in-a-xml-document-?forum=xmlandnetfx), for example.

Comment: And what about *aop* at the begining?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Didn't notice that. You would ideally have a `schemaLocation` entry for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

SchemaLocation must be in the form of 
namespace-name schema-location [namespace-name schema-location]

like example

```
xmlns:mytag="http://www.brajesh.com/tagsDef"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.brajesh.com/tagsDef
                    http://www.brajesh.com/tagsDef.xsd"
```

Here we are conveying to xml that, we are going to use my custom tag that is 'mytag' which is defined in `http://www.brajesh.com/tagsDef` name-space location.
You can validate these tags from `http://www.brajesh.com/tagsDef.xsd` location for `http://www.brajesh.com/tagsDef`.
                             Due to this reason, schema location must have even URLs.